# MapR-DB HBase java client code

Tags: java, hbase, mapr

I need to connect MapR-DB (HBase) via Java code. I have binary tables 'Table01' inside "/mapr/root/main/database"(path). maprcli referring to this path "/mapr/root" and my full table name is "/main/database/Table01".

below hbase shell command works fine, but when I run java code it stopped at 4th line even not showing any error message and terminate also.

```
scan '/main/database/Table01'
```

my java scan code:

```
1.Connection con = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
2.Table table = con.getTable(TableName.valueOf("/main/database/Table01"));
3.Scan scan = new Scan();
4.ResultScanner rs = table.getScanner(scan);
```

my Config Code : I got this config values from 'conf/hbase-site.xml'

```
static Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "XXXX");
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "XXXX");
conf.set("hbase.cluster.distributed","true");
conf.set("hbase.rootdir", "maprfs:///hbase");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you installed and configured the MapR Client? The client is used to indicate to your code to which cluster it must be connected.

You can find the installation instruction:
* [MapR Client Setup](http://here:https://maprdocs.mapr.com/home/AdvancedInstallation/SettingUptheClient-install-mapr-client.html)

2. Do you have any exception that could help us to debug your issue?

Comment: Am not getting any exception. MapR client is installed.